# Wininet's INTERNET_OPTION_IGNORE_OFFLINE doesn't work?

Tags: offline, wininet, internetsetoption

I'm trying to get Wininet to ignore Internet Explorer's "Work Offline" mode, for both HTTP and FTP.

So I'm trying to use `InternetSetOption()` with `INTERNET_OPTION_IGNORE_OFFLINE`.  The documentation says "This is used by `InternetQueryOption` and `InternetSetOption` with a request handle."  However, you can't get a request handle because if IE is in Work Offline mode then `InternetConnect()` will always return a null handle.  Without a connection handle you can't get a request handle.  So I tried using it with an `InternetOpen()` handle and a `NULL` handle.  Both failed with `ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_HANDLE_TYPE`.

Is there a way to get this option to work?  I found a reference on an MS newsgroup from 2003 that `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG` is "broken".  5 years later with IE8 beta 2 and they still haven't fixed it?  Or am I doing it wrong.

**Edit**
I wasn't quite correct.  `InternetConnect()` always returns null if you are on "Work Offline" mode and using FTP, but it returns a valid handle if you are using Http.  However, it still doesn't work even with a request handle.

If I am set to "Work Offline" and I call

```
BOOL a = TRUE;
::InternetSetOption(hData, INTERNET_OPTION_IGNORE_OFFLINE, &a, sizeof(BOOL));
```

on the handle from

```
HINTERNET hData = HttpOpenRequest(hInternet, L"POST", path, NULL, NULL, NULL, flags, 0 );
```

the `InternetSetOption()` call succeeds.
However, the call to `HttpSendRequest()` still fails with error code 2 (file not found), same as it does if I don't set the option.
Same thing if I call

```
::InternetSetOption(hData, INTERNET_OPTION_IGNORE_OFFLINE, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked use of `INTERNET_OPTION_IGNORE_OFFLINE` with the IE 9 version of WinInet and it does seem to work.

Make sure you call InternetSetOption *before* you call HttpOpenRequest and pass in the hInternet handle instead. The option must be set before the request actually gets sent to the server. HttpOpenRequest

+++ Rick ---

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `GET` instead of `POST` which sends additional data in headers?

For example in REST-ful API POST request is equivalent to Create, Update, Delete and GET to Read and that might break the offline mode. Just guessing...